# Using AWS Cognito for authorization with a front end web app to assign roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are looking at integrating AWS Cognito to our web app for authorization but we want a front-end interface to assign roles. Example: An admin can login and create a new user and define roles from our front end app. Once the new user logs in, AWS Cognito should authorize and validate the user and enable the features the user has been given permission to (from the front end web interface). Does AWS Cognito provide APIs for us to integrate with the front end web interface?